# Akka custom dispatcher lookup fails

Tags: scala, akka

Disclaimer: I am only using akka to get the dispatchers and underlaying ExecutionContextExecutor. I am not using any akka actors. I lookup my custom dispatchers defined in config file `application.conf` and then use it in my scala app with future and with parallel collections.

psuedo application.conf:

```
akka {
  my-executor {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now, I am confused by following line in akka docs:

Looking up a Dispatcher

`implicit val executionContext = system.dispatchers.lookup("my-dispatcher")`
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.24//dispatchers.html

What `system` (ActorSystem) is it referring to which knows about all executor config defined in application.conf or is capable of creating dispatcher from that?

Because I tried following and it's failing:

```
implicit val actorSysterm = ActorSystem() 
actorSysterm.dispatchers.lookup("akka.my-executor") //Error: akka.ConfigurationException: Dispatcher [akka.my-executor] not configured
```

Comment: dispatcher definition is outside akka braces. Also there is really no point of using it if you don't use actor. It is using Java executors as underlying implementation so their performance is similar. You can pass Java executors directly into Scala `Future` implicit ExecutorContext parameter using `ExecutorContext.fromExecutor`

Comment: btw if its defined outside akka then why there is no way to access it? as I mention doc assumes that you have `system` in your scope which i don't because I don't use actors

Comment: No its defined outside the braces but you can still access it with `lookup`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in application.conf (note the config is in top level rather than nested inside akka)

```
my-executor {
  ...
}
```

And in your application code:

```scala
implicit val actorSysterm = ActorSystem() 
actorSysterm.dispatchers.lookup("my-executor")
```